# What can I use instead of sprintf?

Tags: embedded, printf, interrupt, string-concatenation, texas-instruments

I am working on TI-TM4C129X ARM board and trying to write a LOG mechanism.It works good when I call it from the Tasks although I faced a problem when I called it with a timer.As I understand that, printf like functions works with Hwi and this causes the error. My aim is to format strings together with the operations like sprintf(),vsprintf(),memcpy() and memset(). How can I solve this problem ? Is there any equivalent methods that success sprintf() operation ?
Thanks for your answers,
Best Regards.

Comment: Please give a rough explanation what Hwi is and why you think this causes a problem. As far as general understanding of C standard library functions is concerned, there is the theoretical caveat that none of them is required to be thread or interrupt safe, although in practical use, at least `sprintf` should perform without problems.

Comment: It is always a bad idea to use stdio.h in general, but particularly so on microcontroller applications. Simply roll out your own string conversion routine, you only need to do so once in your life and then you are set. It is a trivial thing to program.

Comment: "When I called it with a timer."  Does this mean you're also trying to do logging functions from inside interrupt service routines?  If so, this is a horrible idea.  Interrupt service routines should generally be kept as small as possible.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the printf is the problem, not sprintf. Assuming your Log message uses an interrupt (UARTs do), and your timer is called from an interrupt, then your options are limited.

I would set a flag in the timer that your task code can check, once outside the context of the timer.  This flag could indicate one of several messages to print, even include a time stamp if that helps to resort things afterwards, since your printed messages will not be in order.

Or, with SWO output (like the Segger j-link), you should be able to just send the data. But to avoid scrambled sentences, you need to halt interrupts while sending out a debug message, which obviously can affect the real-time behavior.